# Create new dataframe with column counting upward to a certain value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new dataframe in python with only one column containing numbers counting up to a certain point, e.g. 150,000. So it would start at 1, 2, 3, .... to 149,998, 149,999, 150,000. I was thinking about loops but not sure about the exact execution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a data frame with only one column which contains numbers from 0 to 150000.

```
import pandas as pd 

df =pd.DataFrame(range(150000))
```

Then you need to print it out :

```
print(df)
```